# How can I add alias email to my new account?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I set up a new domain and a new email address. Now I want to set up alias email (gmail) but it doesn't allow me to do so. There is no option available in the new account but there is in an old one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you just have the domain name, you will not be able to add it as an alias to your Gmail account.

however I suggest you to purchase one basic G suite subscription and use the domain that you purchased for that account. In that way you can create an email address with that domain and if you want that those emails go to your gmail account you can set up a forwarding rule.

The process to create the forwarding rule is explained here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en